# How to increase the response size of the exception thrown via WCF

Tags: c#, wcf

I get the following error

```
System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException: The content type text/html; charset=utf-8 of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly. The first 1024 bytes of the response were: '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" http-equiv="content-type">
<title>Error Page</title>
<style type="text/css">
body,div,dl,dt,dd,ul,ol,li,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,pre,form,fieldset,input,textarea,p,blockquote,th,td
{ margin: 0px;padding: 0px; font-family:Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;}
html{width: 100%;height: 100%;overflow: auto;}
a img { border: medium none;}
.outer_Container {text-align: center;}
.outer_Wrap {width: 1000px;margin: auto;text-align: left;}
.contentWrapper {width: 1000px;background-color: #fff;}
.header {float: left;width: 1000px;height: 84px; /*background-image: url("/errorPage/TopBlueGradient.png"); */ background-image: url("/utils/images/header_bknd.png");background-repeat: repeat-x;}
.tittleOuter { float: left; width: 630px; margin-left: 8px; margin-top: 20px;}
.tittle {width: 630px;float: left;font-size: 18px;color: #FFFFFF;line-height: 18px;}
.tittle_Sub {float: lef'.

Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ValidateRequestReplyResponse(HttpWebRequest request, HttpWebResponse response, HttpChannelFactory factory, WebException responseException, ChannelBinding channelBinding)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at Intel.IsvWebService.Client.IRefurbishService.CheckServiceStatus()
   at Intel.Refurbish.WebService.RefurbishWS.ATCheckServiceStatus(ServiceStatusRequest request)
```

There are only first 1024 bytes that is being displayed as a part of the error thrown. Is there a way that I can increase the size to unlimited to that I can see the full HTML code?

Comment: Use Fiddler to see the full response

Answer (score 4):

In System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities:

```
Stream responseStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
long num = webResponse.ContentLength;
if (num < 0L || num > 1024L)
{
    num = 1024L;
}
// More code...
```

It's hard coded to grab the first 1024 bytes or less if the length of the response is smaller. Really annoying because the root error is ending up further down in the response for me....

Comment: ərgh Microsoft :-(

Answer (score -1):

Increase the size of maxBufferPoolSize,maxBufferSize,maxReceivedMessageSize and readerQuotas attribute.

Ex:

```
 <netNamedPipeBinding>
    <binding
       name="NetNamedPipeBinding"
       openTimeout="00:01:00"
       receiveTimeout="00:01:00"
       sendTimeout="00:01:00"
       closeTimeout="00:01:00"
       hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
       maxBufferPoolSize="2147483646"
       maxBufferSize="2147483646"
       maxConnections="500"
       maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483646"
       transactionFlow="false"
       transactionProtocol="OleTransactions"
       transferMode="Buffered">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign" />
      </security>
      <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="2147483646"
                    maxBytesPerRead="2147483646"
                    maxDepth="999"
                    maxNameTableCharCount="2147483646"
                    maxStringContentLength="2147483646" />
    </binding>
  </netNamedPipeBinding>
```